# How to create index for dic in mongodb with python?

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, dictionary, indexing

I have some objects like:

```
{
    'id':1
    'claims':{
        'c1':{xxxxx},
        'c8':{xxxxx},
        'c20':{xxxxx}
    }
}
```

if I use `d.create_index([('claims', 1)])` directly, it will use whole `{'c1':{xxxxx},'c8':{xxxxx},'c20':{xxxxx}}` as index which is not what I want. I want just use 'c1', 'c8', 'c20' as keys. I read the document said that if it is an array like:

```
{
    'id':1
    'claims':[
        'c1':{xxxxx},
        'c8':{xxxxx},
        'c20':{xxxxx}
    ]
}
```

It will be possible. And I want to know if this can be done when it is a dict. or how can I convert it into an array?

Answer (score 1):

The way of doing that is as follows:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { 'claims.c1':1, 'claims.c8':1, 'claims.c20':1 } )
```